# How to Get default Value of Session Waring?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, web

I'm using the following code to get value of Session warning.But when i run the code i'm getting the error of Null Reference.

```
function pageLoad() {
    var millisecTimeOutWarning = "<%= int.Parse(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SessionTimeoutWarning"].ToString()) * 60 * 1000 %>";
    alert(millisecTimeOutWarning);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code don't have any issue, it will work if the AppSetting key `SessionTimeoutWarning` exists.

`ConfigurationManager.AppSettings` throws `'System.NullReferenceException'` when the key doesn't exists.

Please check your configuration and make sure that the key exists.

Remember that `AppSettings` is a `NameValueCollection` object returned by `ConfigurationManager`

```
 public static NameValueCollection AppSettings
        {
            get
            {
                object section = GetSection("appSettings");
                if (!(section is NameValueCollection))
                {
                    // If config is null or not the type we expect, the declaration was changed. 
                    // Treat it as a configuration error.
                    throw new ConfigurationErrorsException(SR.Config_appsettings_declaration_invalid);
                }

            return (NameValueCollection)section;
        }
    }
```

If you try to get a value of a Key from NameValueCollection, it will return null, and if you do a ToString() to null, you will get `'System.NullReferenceException'`

For example, following code will return the same error which you are getting.

```
 NameValueCollection AppSettings = new NameValueCollection();
 AppSettings.Add("Key1", "1");
 Debug.Write(AppSettings["Key2"].ToString());
```

Comment: <configuration>
  <appSettings>
      <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None" />
    </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  <sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="3" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>

My Config file

Comment: <configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None" />
    <add key="SessionTimeoutWarning" value="20"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="3" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>

Comment: your key is not there.. add it (Replace with what have a sent)